# linking accounts to campaigns

Tags: campaign

I need to link campaigns to accounts. I hear its not possible out of the box, but a work around can be created. I'm also willing to download an app. If other organizations are doing this, can someone please explain the steps to their work around or recommend an app?

Comment: Why don't you create a lookup field on Campaign that points to Account. Why is that not possible? I think I'm missing something.

Answer (score 4):

One possible solution is create a new object `Account_Campaign_Members`. Which is a join object between `Account` & `Campaign` (It has 2 Lookup references to both Objects) And then update the `CampaignView` page adding a component to see all those Account Campaign Members along with the `Leads`&`Contacts`.

It's a bit laborious since everything that you want to copy from normal `CampaignMembers` you'll have to create it by yourself but it gives you the most flexibility since emulates the same behaviour than normal `CampaignMembers`.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can go to Campaign object and create a custom field of type `Lookup Relationship` that points to Account object. This will create a link between Campaign and Account objects in a way that one Account can have multiple Campaign records associated to it.

If you need the ability to have multiple Accounts associated with one Campaign record, then you would go to Account object instead, and create a `Lookup Relationship` from there.

If you need many to many relationship you'll have to create a new custom object and create a `Master-Detail Relationship` from that object to both Account and Campaign objects.

I hope this can help you.

Comment: That won't work, especially if you want an Account to be associated with multiple campaigns and a Campaign to have multiple accounts associated with it. The best way to do this is to create a function object with master-detail relationships, as to create a many-to-many relationship between Account and Campaign.

Comment: @KruseinSalesforce didn't I said the same in the third paragraph?